# If someone stole the hard drive of the database and don't have account & password, can he see the data?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, security, database

If someone stole the hard drive of the database and don't have account & password, can he see the data?Our company have MySQL and mongoDB. thank you very much.

Comment: assuming you did not explicitely encrypt the drive, yes they can probably see the data. You can very easily reset the password/ bypass authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, MySQL and Mongo DB **do not store data on disk in an encrypted format**. If you do not have full disk encryption or similar, anybody with access to read the drive can read the data.

Both MySQL and Mongo DB *do* offer disk encryption on enterprise offerings, though there are also third-party options.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 3.2 (and later) enterprise version does support encryption of data on disk with the WiredTiger storage engine.You can find details about encryption [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/).

If you don't explicitly encrypt the data using either MongoDB in built encryption or some other third party tool, then yes, data can be read as the default behaviour is not to encrypt data.